# Sass.js online compilation

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass

OK, I am a bit confused. I've downloaded and included the [sass.js](https://github.com/medialize/sass.js/) files into my webpage `head` section:

```
<script src="assets/plugins/sassjs/sass.js"></script>
```

This is the code I have in the `body` part:

```
<span id="foo">This text should be green</span>
```

Below is the code I try to compile (placed in the `head` section too):

```
    <script>
    // init a SAAS instance
    var sass = new Sass();

    // Example
    var scss = '$color: green; #f00 { color: $color; }';
    sass.compile(scss, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
    </script>
```

As a result I do have the compilation result output in the console, however the styles won't apply. Am I missing something and this is to be used with Node.js only? I really don't understand how this should work.

Comment: I'm just curious, why do you want to do this? What's the advantage over using node-sass?

Comment: @1252748, oh I use the node-sass compiler for production, however working on a tool to let users preview the changes they've done live in their browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `<style>` element and insert the result to it:

```
// in HTML
<style id="sass"></style>

// in JS
document.getElementById('sass').innerText = result.text;
```

Comment: Thanks! However, the `result` content looks more like a json object rather than a css string: https://github.com/medialize/sass.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#the-response-object. Sorry for asking before trying it (I am away from my working computer). Is this a tested solution?

Comment: Well this was just a prove of concept :] I updated the example to use `result.text` as your link suggests.

Comment: Btw there is no such thing as JSON object :] JSON is string representation of JS object (POJO) :]